# Please help me to figure out 1D heat PDE problem by Laplace transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, heat-equation

My text book does not show any relative stuff. I am very confusing to solve this problem. Thank you.

Transient heat conduction in 1D. Use Laplace transform to solve given boundary value problem. Give your answer in the form of an integral and simplify as much as possible.

[image]

[image]

[image]